# How many tables we can store in a dataset?

Tags: c#

How many tables we can store in a dataset. How to count the limit of tables in a single dataset

```
Dataset Ds;
Int x=Ds.max tables;
```

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTableCollection.cs,ab77511a29098fb6 look like `DataTableCollection` doesn't imply addition restictions and technically, in could be `2**31 - 1` `(2147483647)` tables

Comment: If you reach a limit, you have *way* too many tables in your data set.

Comment: If you need to know then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @hans why it is wrong?

Comment: @MeerDeen - Hitting the limit of tables would imply something seriously wrong with the overall design. If you have >10k tables, there's a lot of room for improvement to the structure.

Comment: No idea, you didn't explain why you need to know.  But pretty strong evidence that you have absolutely no idea if your program is good enough.  Everybody is going to be *really* unhappy when it is discovered late that it isn't close to meeting its requirements.  That's what project disasters are made of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [`System.Int32.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.MaxValue(v=VS.110).aspx) so 2,147,483,647 because [`DataSet.Tables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`DataTableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) that has a [`Count` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase.count(v=vs.110).aspx) which is of type `System.Int32`.

In practice the memory is the limitation.

But Hans Passant's is right: "if you need to know then you're doing it wrong". So i hope that this is just a theoretical question.

Answer (score 0):

Max size is an Int32. So there are maximum 2.147.483.647 (2 Billion) tables possible.